# colors in Plotly 4.x for R

Tags: r, plotly

I use the new Plotly (4.x) package for R with Shiny. I am colouring my graphs categorically, and if there is only 1 item in a category, the colouring exits with an error. A minimal example would be as follows:

```
plot_ly(head(iris, 1), 
   x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color=~Species,      
   colors = setNames("#FF5748", "setosa"),
   type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
```

> Error in if (has_attr(x$type, "colorscale")) x[["z"]] else NULL : argument is of length zero

The `colors`vector is my named vector, where names refer to Species and the appropriate colour is chosen, always correct if more than one item per Species is present, e.g.:

```
plot_ly(iris[c(1,60),], 
    x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Sepal.Width, color=~Species, 
    colors=setNames(c("#FF5748", "black"), c("setosa", "versicolor")),
    type="scatter", mode="markers")
```

Is this a plotly bug or am I missing something?

Thanks!

**edit:** to be more precise, this problem occurs often when generating subplots and a subplot has only 1 datapoint:

```
colormap <- setNames(c("#FF5748", "black"), c("setosa", "versicolor"))
data <- iris[c(1,2,60), ]

# vars contains the facet variables
vars <- levels(factor(data$Species))

# build a list of length(var) plots
plots <- lapply(vars, function(species) {
  data <- subset(data, Species==species)
  plot_ly(data, x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Sepal.Width) %>%
    add_bars(color=~Species, colors=colormap) 
})

p <- subplot(plots, nrows = length(plots), shareX = TRUE, titleX = FALSE)
```

This code produces the error, while using `color = factor(data$Species)` works fine. Thanks dww!

Comment: removed tag `shiny` - this is only a plotly issue

Comment: See my answer below - so far as I can tell this is a bug. I can't find a related issue at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues, so I would suggest opening a bug report at this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm replicating this issue. It occurs when

1. the data has only one row,
2. and a `color =` argument is passed to `plot_ly` or `add_trace`.
3. and the column used for color has factor levels that are not present

We can see that the 3rd of these criteria is needed to replicate the problem, as this gives an error:

```
pdata = head(iris, 1)
plot_ly(pdata, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width,
          color = pdata$Species,
          colors = setNames("#FF5748", "setosa"),
          type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
```

But this does not:

```
plot_ly(pdata, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, 
         color = factor(pdata$Species),      
         colors = setNames("#FF5748", "setosa"),
         type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
```

This looks like a bug. For the moment, you can sidestep the issue using the 2nd structure above that refactors your color column. Note that you will need to use `$` notation rather than `~` to reference the column.

### UPDATE

Bug has now been fixed in latest github commit
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/commit/724b440578f954593e9d6ce555bca8b143fc9e6d

Comment: Thanks, you are a genius. With that tip the code is working. This problem occurs often when generating subplot, I edited my original question with the problem code. Thanks again!

Comment: That was quick - bug has been fixed already (1/2 hour after opening the issue) on current master at github https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/commit/724b440578f954593e9d6ce555bca8b143fc9e6d